# Does the Pons Asinorum also hold for spherical or hyperbolic triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

Does the Pons Asinorum also hold for spherical or hyperbolic triangles?

I've tried to prove it but I can't figure it out. I think it does hold for the spherical triangles, not sure about the hyperbolic ones.

Comment: Look through the first five propositions in *Elements*.  Does Euclid invoke at any point the parallel postulate?

Comment: Pons asinorum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum)

Comment: See prop. 7 in (https://msu.edu/~ottensam/Otten_842_HYPERBOLIC.doc)